# JComboBox and string formatting

Tags: java, string-formatting, jcombobox

I've been trying to use String.format to display in the JComboBox, something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString(){ return String.format("%-40s %4d", title, n); }
```

But the result is:
[JComboBox's appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k00qZ.png)

Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: [Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aah3D.png)

Comment: what would be your desired output ?

Comment: Like the console result.

Comment: where is the console result? include it to your question.

Comment: There we go, included

Comment: is 123 and 123 on top is separate String or on 1 String?

Comment: It's one string per line, exacly "String.format("%-40s %4d", title, n);"

Answer (score 0):

Try this when on your addItem:

```
cmb1.addItem(String.format("%-40s %39d", "123",123)); // %4d to %39d
cmb1.addItem(String.format("%-40s %4d", "123456789012345678901234567890",-12));
```

It is different in console and when you add it in `JComboBox` because in console, It will automatically find the largest length and pad spaces to the other String you format, but in **JComboBox**, you need to manually change your second argument to align to the next Item in **JComboBox**.

Comment: It worked, but was not what I expected. If I need to manually change the format parameter, doesn't make sense to try to format. The real problem are that the spaces don't have the same lenght of the letters, I think I'll have to use a monospaced font, that's why I asked if there was something that could be done besides change the font.